# UVproject modifiers failing

Tags: texturing, modifiers

how do i use 2 different textures through the UV project?

how do I do when using modifier : UVproject so the image doesn't cross to the other side of the model like in the image?[image]

and how do I make it so that when I use more than one projector the image doesn't get flawed as in the image?

[image]

Comment: to guess an answer to the first part of your question, I think all you need to do is to hide the other part of the mesh, before UV Projecting. That should prevent the image from appearing on both sides

Comment: did not work . have another suggestion?

Comment: I tried it, and it did work. I can't post pictures in comments, if I could've, I would've shown it to you.
I don't have an answer to the 2nd part of your post, that's why I'm not posting what I did as an answer

Comment: do you have a tutorial on how to hide the other part of the mesh, before UV Projecting?how is it possible to have several uv maps and the texture used in it is always aligned as if it were applied to a normal object?